# How to share internet over wifi without commands?

Tags: wifi

How can i share internet over WiFi. I am bad at using commands is there any easy way?

Comment: How is this a security question?

Comment: i am new at that how can i change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many softwares to do things like this, but if you are looking for free then [SoftHotspot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/softhotspot/) and [Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) are good.

SoftHotspot is good in user interface and it will also give you some more features than Virtual Router. it will also give you notifications when new user connect/disconnect to your hotspot network.

Virtual Router is also good and easy to use.